# PHP Date Formatting Not Working Correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Advanced Custom fields in wordpress to input the start and end date of a particular tour. That date is formated mmddyy (10052013).

I'm trying to use PHP to format the date. The code is as follows:

```
<?php 
            $date = get_field('start_date');

            $y = substr($date, 4, 4); $m = substr($date, 0, 2); $d = substr($date, 2, 2);

            // create UNIX
            $time = strtotime("{$d}-{$m}-{$y}");

            // format date (November 11th 1988)
            echo date('F n, Y', $time); 
        ?>
        <?php
            if(get_field('end_date')){
                $date = get_field('end_date');

                $y = substr($date, 4, 4); $m = substr($date, 0, 2); $d = substr($date, 2, 2);

                // create UNIX
                $time = strtotime("{$d}-{$m}-{$y}");

                // format date (November 11th 1988)
                echo ' - ' . date('F n, Y', $time); 
                }
            ?>
```

But when the dates are rendered on the page, for some reason, the date is always "October 10, 2013" and I don't know why. You can see it in action here: http://onedirectionconnection.com/tester/?projects=take-me-home-tour

I output the database values as they're saved normally to show that they're definitely saved correctly. It's something going wrong in the way I coded the PHP.

Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo ' - ' . date('F d, Y', $time);
```

You're creating the date correctly, but both `F` and `n` refer to the month.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

See it working here: https://eval.in/52927

Answer (score 1):

`n` is numeric month

`j` is day numeric without leading zero, and what you're looking for

```
echo ' - ' . date('F j, Y', $time);
```